# Ordering a grouped array

Tags: swift

Is it possible to order a grouped array by date desc or asc?

I am pulling a list of diary appointments from a JSON web service and I'm grouping them by date. The grouping is working well (I'm using the appointment date in a Supplementary view in a collection view as a header) and all appointments are showing within their respective headers correctly, however the dates are all out of order?

My code is below:

```
do {
    if !self.appointments.isEmpty {
        self.appointments.removeAll()
    }
    if !self.groupedAppointments.isEmpty {
        self.groupedAppointments.removeAll()
    }
    self.appointments = try JSONDecoder().decode([DiaryAppointment].self, from: data!)

    let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: self.appointments) { (appointment) -> String in
        return appointment.appointmentDate!
    }

    let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()

    keys.forEach({
        self.groupedAppointments.append(groupedDictionary[$0]!)
    })

    self.diaryList.reloadData()

    completionHandler(success, nil)
} catch let error {
    print("This went wrong", error)
    completionHandler(success, error)
}
```

....

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return groupedAppointments.count > 0 ? groupedAppointments.count : 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if groupedAppointments.count > 0 {
        return groupedAppointments[section].count
    }
    return appointments.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerID, for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader {
        if !self.groupedAppointments.isEmpty {
            sectionHeader.headerLabel.text = self.groupedAppointments[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].appointmentDate
        }
        return sectionHeader
    }

    return UICollectionReusableView()
}
```

The above gives me the correct amount of sections, with the correct dates displayed in the header and correct cells displayed within the sections. But the sections are not ordered by date.

Comment: Your date property seems to be of type String, to get a proper sorting you need to convert it to `Date` first.

Comment: Yep, converted to date and it just worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appointmentDate` is `String` type, convert to date and then you can use `ComparisonResult`

```
groupedDictionary.keys.sorted(by: {$0.compare($1) == .orderedDescending })
```

Comment: This is already done when getting the keys, `let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()`

Comment: No extra sorting required. Converting to date and the array was sorting correctly as @JoakimDanielson said. Thanks